# How to run a interactive shell script in crontab

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have a shell script, when run this script it will promote a question, need user input yes or no.but now, i need run this script on crontab. How to resolve this problem.

Comment: Make the script non-interactive.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you seem to run an *interactive* script, not a *non interactive* one, as your title suggests.

If this script reads the user input from stdin (and not directly from the terminal), write a wrapper script which provides the necessary input via a pipe, and run this wrapper from cron.

Comment: You can add an example like `echo y | yourscript.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to prompt the questions to some user who is logged in at the moment I believe it's not possible. Because when you run it with cron it will run the sh in a different terminal. So the user won't be able to answer the prompted questions.

But if you'll give some static or calculated answers to these prompted questions than you can create a wrapper script just like others suggest. But this also means you can put these values hardcoded in to the main script. So probably that's not what you want.